# attr_writer of array

Tags: ruby

I'm confused with Ruby's attr_writer.
I'm trying to add a value inside an array but i'm encountering the following error:

> Line 13: undefined method `test' for # (NoMethodError)

```
class Pet
  attr_writer :test
  def initialize()
    @test = []
  end
end

pet = Pet.new()
pet.test << "Test was a pet"
```

Why? As I understand it, attr_writer is equivalent to a setter method. 
Please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `attr_writer` defines a setter method. But your code tries to use a getter

```
pet.test << "Test was a pet"
```

Here's how ruby sees it (more or less)

```
t = pet.test
t << "Test was a pet"
```

If you actually set an array, it will work

```
pet.test = ['Test was a pet']
```

*As a side note: I personally consider write-only properties as a code smell. Something is probably wrong here. I have never had to use write-only attributes in my career.*

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use [attr_accessor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) method. This way you are able to define setter and getter variables with a single line of code. With the accessor method in place you can either retrieve the defined instance variable value or set another value.

In your code you are trying to initialize a getter method even you are defined your method as a setter.

```
attr_accessor :test
...
print pet.test << "Test was a pet" # => ["Test was a pet"]
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but you're not answering the question. Or, rather, you're answering another question, not the one asked.

Comment: I hate anonymous down votes. In such cases I delete my answer. You should rectify two things : 1) _You can access the same method ..._ -> You can access the same instance variable @test either retrieving it with the getter method `test` or setting a value to it with the setter method `test=`. 2) _In your code you are trying ..._ -> In your code you are trying to push a value into the result of the expression `pet.test`, but `test` is undefined. `attr_writer :test` only defines `test=` (note that the equal sign belongs to the name, it's a syntactic sugar that enable to write `test   = ...`).

Comment: @BernardK Oh yes, now i realize i made a little mistype, i was thought about instance variables, but i wrote methods. I posted only a fragment of the original code....